# Kerberos Authentication support for Jersey 1.X Client

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jersey, jersey-client

We have a REST service secured using Kerberos Authentication. I am using Jersey 1.8 for consuming this service.

I am able to invoke the service's basic auth endpoint which is relatively straight forward. However, I am trying to figure out mechanism supported by Jersey for Kerberos Authentication.

Unfortunately there are not clear guideline/documentation I have been able to find. Most close thing I found is https://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/writing-powerful-rest-client-using-the-asynchttpclient-library-and-jersey/

What is the recommended approach for supporting Kerberos Auth in Jersey ? Your inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a supplement information, I ended up using Apache CXF for REST client and found that it Kerberos authentication works just fine there.  Most trivial part of my exercise was to figuring out kerberos configuration file required, as unfortunately customer I was working for, did not had in house expertise for the same.